# Potentially equal complexity classes without known contradictory relativizations

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, relativization

What are some examples of pairs of complexity classes $A$ and $B$ such that

1. we do not know whether $A=B$, and
2. we do not know contradictory relativizations either (i.e., we do not know oracles $P$ and $Q$ such that $A^P = B^P$ and $A^Q \ne B^Q$)?

To phrase the question another way, what are some exceptions to the heuristic that if can't figure out contradictory relativizations then it is easy to resolve the equality question outright?

Comment: Would any two classes A and B for which we do not know how to prove an oracle separation between A and B suffice to answer your question? (Assuming it is possible for A and B to be equal.)

Comment: Would you accept examples about implications between equalities, rather than single equalities? For example, we do not know whether NP=UP implies that PH collapses, but we also don't have an oracle in which this implication is false.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow : That is interesting, although I am slightly more interested in the specific type of example I described.

Comment: @Robin Kothari : If we don't know an oracle Q, then a fortiori we don't know oracles P and Q, so the only way I see for (A,B) to satisfy your requirements but not mine is if we *know* that A=B but we don't know an oracle that separates them.  I guess it might be interesting to see an example of A and B such that A = B yet it's plausible (but not known) that they could be separated by an oracle, but this isn't really what I was asking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the biggest such example at present is $BQP $ (quantum polybomial time) vs $PH $ (the polynomial time hierarchy). **Significant** effort has been put into separating them relative to an oracle, with no success. (Of course a powerful enough oracle will make them equal.) And the best known containment result is that $BQP $ is in $PP $.

Some references for attacks on the oracle problem:
http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4698
http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0305

Comment: Actually the best known result is $\mathsf{BQP \subseteq AWPP \subseteq PP}$, where $\mathsf{AWPP}$ is (among other things) the largest gap-definable sublcass of $\mathsf{PP}$ such that $\mathsf{PP^{AWPP} = PP}$. I'm not aware of any interest in the class $\mathsf{AWPP}$ apart from its relationship to $\mathsf{BQP}$ and to $\mathsf{PP}$, so as a refinement this is a bit of a technical point, but there you go.

Comment: Along these lines, it's also not known how to separate BQP from AM, or even QMA from AM.

Answer (score 5):

Is there an oracle known to separate $\mathsf{P}^{\#\mathsf{P}}$ from $\mathsf{PSPACE}$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question was intended more rhetorically, i.e. "I think this is an answer, but maybe there's an oracle known that I'm not aware of"

Comment: Yes, thanks Josh. Do you know one? It's very hard to search for, but I recall being unable to learn of one's existence last time I tried.